# validar formulario con laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validación

Hola estoy intentando validar los campos del formulario que he creado con la función validate de laravel, le paso datos validos y no valida.

```
 $request->validate([
            'player' => 'alpha_dash',
            'spec.*' => 'integer|distinct|min:2',
            'realm' => 'alpha_dash',
            'faction' => 'alpha',
        ]);
```

Es extraño porque el campo player si me lo valida pero realm y faction no. le estoy introduciendo valores como Alliance, Horde, Both a faction o nombres de Reinos con caracteres alpha a realm.

Answer (score -1):

Estaba pasando porque el campo player y spec estaban vacios y por tanto no validaba jeje.

tuve que añadir la clausula nullable a la validación:

```
$request->validate([
            'player' => 'nullable|alpha_dash',
            'spec.*' => 'nullable|integer|distinct|min:2',
            'realm' => 'alpha_dash',
            'faction' => 'alpha',
        ]);
```

saludos